# Amazon S3 Access Denied when calling aws lambda publish-layer-version CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, aws-cli

I tried to run `aws lambda publish-layer-version` command line in my local console using my personal aws credentials, but I've got an Amazon S3 Access Denied error for the bucket in which the zip layer is stored.

```
aws lambda publish-layer-version --layer-name layer_name --content S3Bucket=bucket_name,S3Key=layers/libs.zip
```

```
An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the PublishLayerVersion operation: Your access has been denied by S3, please make sure your request credentials have permission to GetObject for {URI of layer in my S3 bucket}. S3 Error Code: AccessDenied. S3 Error Message: Access Denied
```

When I'm running the `aws cp` command in the same bucket, it all works perfectly fine

```
aws s3 cp s3://bucket_name/layers/libs.zip libs.zip
```

So I assume that the aws lambda command line is using an other role than the one used when I'm running the aws cp command line ? Or maybe it uses another mecanism that I just don't know. But I couldn't find any thing about it in the AWS documentation.
I've just read that AWS can return a 403 it couldn't find the file. So maybe it could be an issue with the command syntax ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you share the full command that you run to publish? Does it look like something like this : aws lambda publish-layer-version --layer-name hello-world-layer --description "Hello World Layer" --license-info "MIT" --content S3Bucket=lambda-layers-us-east-1-1234567890,S3Key=hello-world-layer.zip

Comment: aws lambda publish-layer-version --layer-name get_paying_user_classification --content S3Bucket=bucket-name,S3Key=layers/get_paying_user_classification_python_libs.zip

Comment: Any ideas @TobievanderMerwe ?

Comment: Can you provide the `s3 cp` command that works?

Comment: And also - do you have any resource policies on the bucket?

Comment: ```aws s3 cp s3://bucket_name/layers/test.zip .```

Comment: No resource policies on this bucket

Comment: Please, is there anyone that can help on this one ?

Comment: Hello, Is there any restriction based on the region, the layer must be in the same bucket's region like the layer ?

Comment: You should post the policies attached to your role as well. Look like they might be missing some critical permissions.

Answer (score 0):

For your call to [publish-layer-version](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/lambda/publish-layer-version.html) you may need to specify the `--content` parameter with **3** parts:

```
S3Bucket=string,S3Key=string,S3ObjectVersion=string
```

It looks like you are missing `S3ObjectVersion`.  I don't know what the AWS behavior is for evaluating and applying the parts of that parameter, but it could be attempting to do something more since the version is not specified and hence giving you that error.  Or it could be returning an error code that is not quite right and is misleading.  Try adding `S3ObjectVersion` and let me know what you get.

Otherwise, AWS permission evaluation can be complex.  I like this [AWS diagram](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/implement-read-only-service-control-policy-in-aws-organizations/) below, so it is a good one to follow to track down permissions issues, but I suspect that AccessDenied is a bit of a red herring in this case:

[image: AWS Permission Flow Diagram]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. You can find an example here : https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/lambda/publish-layer-version.html#examples without the S3ObjectVersion parameter. And object versionning is not enable into my bucket :/

Comment: But I still tried : 
An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the PublishLayerVersion operation: Your access has been denied by S3, please make sure your request credentials have permission to GetObjectVersion for [...]. S3 Error Code: AccessDenied. S3 Error Message: Access Denied

Comment: Does your credential have `GetObjectVersion` permission?  That at least is different from the `GetObject` permission you were seeing before.

Comment: Have you tried the process with a new bucket?  Could there be any SCPs getting applied?  At this point I think you may need to run experiments to try to narrow down the scope to isolate it.  You can run a test with a different bucket to try to rule out a resource-based issue, you can try with a different credential to try to rule out an issue related to the principal, etc.

Comment: Can you also check `CloudTrail` logs to view any events for `PublishLayerVersion` to see what the events show for credentials and other details?

Comment: Yes I tried with an other bucket, and even with a public one. Good idea, I'm gonna check CloudTrail logs !

Comment: Did CloudTrail logs reveal anything?

Comment: Yes, I correctly saw the PublishLayerVersion
My AWS administrator got me admin in my aws account and after that I was able to correctly run PublishLayerVersion from CLI. But we couldn't find out where the permission issue was :'(

Answer (score -1):

Your Lambda does not have privileges (S3:GetObject).
Try running `aws sts get-caller-identity`. This will give you the IAM role your command line is using.
Go to IAM dashboard, check this role associated with your Lambda execution. If you use AWS wizard, it automatically creates a role called oneClick_lambda_s3_exec_role. Click on Show Policy. It will look something like attached image.Make sure `S3:GetObject` is listed.

[image: IAM policy for lambda]

```
Also, AWS returns 403 (access denied) when the file does not exist. Be sure the target file is in the S3 bucket.
```

Comment: My layer is not attached (yet) to a specific lambda function, so "Your Lambda does not have S3:Getobject privileges" makes no sens in this case right ?

Comment: I ran `aws sts get-caller-identity` and it showed my personal creds, with which I have S3:Getobject permission.
Besides, if I ran `aws s3 cp` from this specific bucket and keyname to my local file, it works perfectly.

Comment: user@ubuntu:$ aws lambda publish-layer-version --layer-name test \
        --content S3Bucket=bucket_name,S3Key=layers/test.zip

An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the PublishLayerVersion operation: Your access has been denied by S3, please make sure your request credentials have permission to GetObject for bucket_name/layers/test.zip. S3 Error Code: AccessDenied. S3 Error Message: Access Denied
make: *** [Makefile:24: publish-layer-version] Error 255

Comment: but ; 

user@ubuntu:$ aws s3 cp s3://bucket_name/layers/test.zip .
download: s3://bucket_name/layers/test.zip to ./test.zip

Comment: Please don't post code as screenshots, but properly formatted code blocks.

Comment: @Marcin The screenshot isn't of a code. It is of an AWS IAM policy that shows how s3:getObject permission should look like. But, thanks for the input.

Comment: @MatthieuVeron You are right that if your layer isn't attached to a lambda then lambda permissions don't matter. There are 2 more things you can try. 
1. Check whether you are trying to publish the layer in the same account as the bucket is in. 
2. Check the bucket policy. Try and change it to - 
`{"Version": "2008-10-17","Statement": [{"Sid": "AllowPublicRead","Effect": "Allow", "Principal": {"AWS": "*" },"Action": "s3:GetObject","Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::YOUR-BUCKETNAME/*" }]}`

Comment: @SAIJAL it also applies to JSON - post it as formatted text, not as a screenshot.

Comment: Yes I'm using the same AWS creds for the two command lines : aws s3 cp & aws lambda publish-layer-version